# Twitter bootstrap v 2 button text

Tags: css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, webkit

I'm having a problem in chrome

see http://jsfiddle.net/qLenP/

if you resize the window in chrome the button text is getting cut but in firefox its overflowing.
is there any way to get it working like same in both the browsers.
see the screen shot for more details

[image]

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">
  <button type="button" class="btn span3 btn-large btn-primary">LargebuttonLargebutton</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn span3 btn-large">LargebuttonLargebutton</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply adding:

```
button{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**[This looks OK to me in FF](http://jsfiddle.net/DWFMt/)**

If you want to target specific Bootstrap classes, you can refine the selector accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried giving the overflow property, but the problem is it should look same in both the browsers. the padding its not the same in both the browsers.

Comment: @Nisanth Sojan apologies, the question only mentioned the overflow. You may also want to manually assign padding.